# What is the name of this factor-algebra?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, terminology

In the polynomial algebra $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n]$ consider an ideal $I$ generated by the polynomials of the form $x_i^k-x_i$, $i=1 \ldots n$ and $k=2,3,\ldots.$

Consider the  quotient algebra $A=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n]/I$.
What is the name of the algebra $A$? Any reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to mod $x_i^2-x_i = x_i(x_i-1)$. We have $k[x_i]/(x_i(x_i-1)) \cong k \times k$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. It follows that $A \cong \otimes_{i=1}^{n} (k \times k) \cong k^{2^n}$ as $k$-algebras. It is the universal $k$-algebra generated by $n$ idempotent elements. I don't know a special "name".

Comment: what is the explicit form  of the isomorphism $k[x]/(x(x-1)) \to k \times k $?

Comment: @Leox Map a polynomial $f(x)$ to the pair $(f(0),f(1))$

Comment: Oh..of cource it is $a+b x  \to (a,b).$

Comment: $a + bx \mapsto (a,b)$ is not correct (this doesn't map $1 \mapsto 1$ for example). The explicit form of the isomorphism follows from the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. As egreg already pointed out, this is just $[f] \mapsto (f(0),f(1))$, or even more explicitly $[a+bx]\mapsto (a,a+b)$.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Thank you!